# arraylist userinput in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, user-input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java arraylist to store userinput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455873/java-arraylist-to-store-userinput)

Hi using the code in java how would I add an option of asking the user if they want to put another directory in or not and if not to print all the directories out.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Aaa 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> phone = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    while (true) 
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    name.add(sc.next());
    System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
    phone.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to interact with the user, you must follow these steps :

1) Print a question

2) Scan the answer

3) Analyse the answer like :

```
if (answer.equals("yes"))
    System.out.println("Enter ... informations : ");
else
    System.out.println("Bye");
```

4) Then do your treatment

Anhuin

Comment: fyi: code blocks inside list items need double indentation (8 spaces)

Comment: I removed the list items to solve this problem :)
But thanks you for the tips !

Comment: Thanks for the help it works now :) all I need it doing now is asking after each directory if I want to add another one and if not to print out the arraylist