# java arraylist that stores userinput

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, user-input

how can I get it to go back to start another directory when the user types yes and also how do I print the arraylist out using a print format

thanks

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AAA
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> phone = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 


    {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
        name.add(scanner.next());
        System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
        phone.add(scanner.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Do you want to add a directory yes/no?");
        String answer = scanner.nextLine(); 

        if (answer.equals("yes"));
        //want it to go back to start another direcotry here

        else 
    {

        System.out.println("Thanks for adding to the directory");
        System.out.println(answer());
    }


    }

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java arraylist to store user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455873/java-arraylist-to-store-userinput), also by the same user.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a while true, and then, when the user types no, you break the look. The code seems like this:

```
ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> phone = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 

while(true){
    System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
    name.add(scanner.next());
    System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
    phone.add(scanner.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Do you want to add a directory yes/no?");
    String answer = scanner.next(); 

    if (answer.equals("no")){
        System.out.println("Thanks for adding to the directory");
        System.out.println(answer());
        break; //
    }

}
```

There are another strategies, like using a do/while. But essentially you have to use a loop.

Comment: hi thanks for the help with break in that position in the code it does not let me add more and when i remove it i cant stop adding can you help ?

Comment: Ok, I forgot something. Change the line: String answer = scanner.nextLine() to String answer = scanner.next(), and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily print out an ArrayList:

```
System.out.println(list);
```

It will print something like:

[one, two, three]

where one, two, three are the results of invocation of toString() or array list's elements.

You can remove [] easily by:

```
System.out.println(list.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
```

You you need to use your custom format implement print in loop:

```
for (String s : list) {
    System.out.println(format(s));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class COL {
    public static void main(String [] args) {


        List<Integer> phone = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        Scanner scanner =new Scanner (System.in);

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
            phone.add(scanner.nextInt());

            System.out.println("Do you want to add a directory yes/no?");
            String answer = scanner.next(); 
            if (answer.equals("no")){
                System.out.println("Thanks for adding to the ArrayList");
                System.out.println("\t "+phone);
                break; //
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Addinf brief explanation would be better than just posting a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AAA {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> phone = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String answer = "";

        {
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter your name: ");
                name.add(scanner.next());
                System.out.println("Please enter your number: ");
                phone.add(scanner.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Do you want to add a directory yes/no?");
                answer = scanner.next();
            } while (answer.equals("yes"));
            if (answer.equals("yes")); //want it to go back to start another direcotry here
            else {

                System.out.println("Thanks for adding to the directory");
                for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.print(name.get(i)+"\t");
                    System.out.print(phone.get(i));
                    System.out.println("");
                }
            }


        }

    }
}
```