# how to add user input into a vector and how to search that data

Tags: java, search, vector, user-input

i am new to java. 
i want to add user input into a vector and i want to search them ....

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String Name;
String Address;
Name = input.nextLine();
Address = input.nextLine();
```

how to put those 2 input into a vector and those Name and Address must work like a pair i mean *if i store Name = john and Address = Canada(whatever)* ... **if i search John it will show ... John from Canada.** sumthing like this.
and if i add like 50 name and address into that vector i want to search them by name ... how to do it?

as i dont know how vector works plz show me how to store user input and how to search them.

**it will be kind if you show me the same thing in Arraylist.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858572/how-to-make-a-new-list-in-java

Comment: can your name be duplicate? if not you can use HashMap

Comment: ya name can be same ...

Comment: all i want to know is how to put 2 user input into a vector and how to search them ... plz dont mind if my question is not clear i am new to java.

Comment: A Key- Value pair type is wht will be useful for you. Check http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/AddingKeyValuePairs.htm or jsut search for "key value pair java"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Vector is [not commonly used anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated). You could use a combination of lists and maps, as explained [in this post](http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and), but maybe you could just make Person objects with name and address and add them to an ArrayList in stead?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add( new Person("John", "Canada") );
        persons.add( new Person("John", "USA") );
        persons.add( new Person("John", "Mexico") );

        //java 8
        persons.stream().forEach((p) -> {
            System.out.println("Name: " + p.getName() +", Address: "+ p.getAddress());
        });

        //java 7
        for(Person p : persons){
            System.out.println("Name: " + p.getName() +", Address: "+ p.getAddress());
        }

    }

}

class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final String address;

    public Person(String name, String address){
        this.name = name; 
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

}
```

Comment: how to do that ... making person object with name and address and add that object to an Arraylist or vector?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460788/java-arraylist-that-stores-userinput in this post he use 2 arraylist 1 for number and for name ... how can i do that by using 1 arraylist? is it possible?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to make Person objects.

Comment: this is what i am looking for ... i have another question .... if i add many name and address and i want to search them from that arraylist how can i search them by name?